# Запрет наследования метода класса в PHP

Tags: php, веб-программирование, ооп, классы, наследование

Для запрета наследования целого класса в PHP есть ключевое слово final:

```
final class Test
{
}
```

Тоже самое ключевое слово можно применять в отношении методов класса:

```
class Test
{
   final public function test_echo()
   {
   }
}
```

Но в этом случае final запрещает лишь переопределение метода. Возможно ли также запретить наследование метода, при этом не делая его private, чтобы он также был доступен из экземпляра класса? Предположим я хочу расширить определенный класс, добавив в него один метод и сохранить свойства, но большинство других методов в этом классе нельзя использовать.

Comment: я ничего не понял.

Comment: возможно вашу задачу можно решить композицией, вместо  наследования?

Comment: final protected?

Comment: @Jigius что вы имеете ввиду под композицией?

Comment: @TotalPusher final protected ровно также не позволит переопределить метод, но он будет наследован

Comment: @Ипатьев прочитайте про наследование в ООП и ключевое слово final в PHP

Comment: @krown_loki почитать можно [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/325478/)

Comment: @krown_loki и где написано, что final public function запрещает  переопределение класса? И почему вопрос про запрет использования написан под заголовком запрет наследования?

Comment: @Ипатьев имелось ввиду запрет переопределение метода, а не класса.
Вопрос не в запрете использования, а наследовании класса без некоторых публичных методов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наследование в программировании подразумевает **расширение функционала** (не обязательно, конечно, "сужение" иногда тоже имеет место быть). Мы можем добавить в классы-наследники новые свойства и методы, но не имеем возможности удалить что-то, определенное в классе-родителе. 
Максимум что мы можем сделать, это определить метод или свойство как приватное, но это просто сделает его не доступным у классов-предков.